# Flutter get continuous stream of data from MethodChannels native api

Tags: flutter

I am using Method Channel to integrate android s3 upload . 
Upload is working alright. The android sdk provides two methods onStateChanged and OnProgressChanged to tell state of upload and how many bytes have been uploaded. The problem is I can't seem to get this data returned from the method channel to main flutter file.

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
private static final String CHANNEL = "s3integration";
AmazonS3 s3Client;

String bucket = "instituteimages";
@Override
public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
s3credentialsProvider();
new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(),CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler((call, result)->{
  if(call.method.equals("uploadFiles")){

    String filePath = call.argument("path");
    String fileName = call.argument("fileName");

    File uploadFile = new File(filePath);

    TransferUtility transferUtility= new TransferUtility(s3Client,getApplicationContext());
    TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload(
            bucket,          /* The bucket to upload to */
            fileName,/* The key for the uploaded object */
            uploadFile       /* The file where the data to upload exists */
    );

    transferObserverListener(transferObserver);
    TransferState finalState = transferObserver.getState();



    HashMap<String,String> statusJson= new HashMap<>();
    statusJson.put("status","Success");
    statusJson.put("url",String.format("https://awsurl/%s",fileName));
    result.success(statusJson);
  }



});





public void transferObserverListener(TransferObserver transferObserver) {

transferObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {

  @Override
  public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "State Change"
            + state, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


  }

  @Override
  public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
    int percentage = (int) (bytesCurrent / bytesTotal * 100);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uploading ..."
            + percentage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
    Log.e("error", "error");
  }

});
}
```

As you can see I can get the required states and values from OnStateChanged and OnProgressChanged but I can't return them in result.success, if I do that only the initial values of these variables are returned not the continues stream of them.

Here is flutter code I am calling this upload code from:

```
class UploadVideo extends StatefulWidget {
TeacherUser user = TeacherUser();
UploadVideo(this.user);
@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
return _UploadVideo(this.user);
}
}

class _UploadVideo extends State<UploadVideo> {
  TeacherUser user = TeacherUser();
  _UploadVideo(this.user);
  static const aws_platform = const MethodChannel('s3integration');




String baseBucketUrl = 'https://s3baseurl/';


String title = titleTextController.text;
String path = imagePath.path;
String fileName = imagePath.path.toString().split('/').last.toString();
try{

  var res = await aws_platform.invokeMethod('uploadFiles','path':path,'fileName':fileName});


if(res['status']=='Success'){

var response = postUploadVideo(
    user.key, title, groupSub, groupChap, finalUrl, generalVideo);

print('total response ${response.toString()}');
Navigator.pop(context);
}
else{
  Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Upload failed. Please try again.');
Navigator.pop(context);
}


Navigator.pop(context);
}
on PlatformException catch(e){
  print('platform error ${e.toString()}');

}
```

How can I receive stream of data from MethodChannel so that I can show some kind of progress bar in my flutter code.

Comment: Hi Prashant,
You might find this article helpful.
https://medium.com/@svenasse/flutter-event-channels-89623ce6c017

Comment: You should use [EventChannel](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/EventChannel.html) instead of `MethodChannel` to listen stream of datas, I suggest to see any of example in flutter's plugin source code, because any articles might be outdated since EmbedderV2 was comming out and keep updating.

Answer (score 0):

you can used EventChannel to handle stream

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
public static final String STREAM = "com.yourcompany.eventchannelsample/stream";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new EventChannel(getFlutterView(), STREAM).setStreamHandler(
            new EventChannel.StreamHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onListen(Object args, final EventChannel.EventSink events) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "adding listener");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel(Object args) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "cancelling listener");
                }
            }
    );
}
```